Slow simulation speed of a Very High frequency circuit (LTspice)
I've been working on optimizing the simulation time for a larger circuit.  Before asking for assistance, I experimented with several approaches:

Adjusting simulation settings, such as altering figures like abstol=1e-3 and reltol=1e-3 to allow for larger acceptable errors, changing integration methods, and ensuring maximum threads.
Using ideal components
Implementing hierarchical circuits, including one with a full-wave rectifier and two with either C1 or C2 in the sub-circuit.  This did not yield any noticeable improvement in speed.
Introducing parasitic elements.
Altering the frequency of the source to 6000 or 60000 and recalculating a new capacitance for C2 to emulate the results of 600 MHz. While effective, I find this approach cumbersome and prone to errors in the translation of results and I prefer to maintain all component values at their original values.


Circuit File Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/173LEKFZN4g9EQpY4oLSydQAMbqDpKQX8/view?usp=sharing
As plain text:
SHEET 1 1072 680
WIRE -64 -48 -272 -48
WIRE -64 0 -64 -48
WIRE -64 0 -144 0
WIRE 0 0 -64 0
WIRE -464 80 -528 80
WIRE -352 80 -384 80
WIRE -272 80 -272 -48
WIRE -272 80 -288 80
WIRE 0 96 0 64
WIRE 128 96 0 96
WIRE -144 112 -144 64
WIRE -144 112 -224 112
WIRE -144 128 -144 112
WIRE 0 128 0 96
WIRE -64 192 -144 192
WIRE 0 192 -64 192
WIRE 128 288 128 96
WIRE -528 336 -528 80
WIRE -64 336 -64 192
WIRE -64 336 -528 336
WIRE -224 384 -224 112
WIRE 128 384 128 352
WIRE 128 384 -224 384
WIRE 128 416 128 384
FLAG 128 416 0
SYMBOL cap 112 288 R0
WINDOW 3 1 55 Left 2
SYMATTR Value 20mf
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR SpiceLine Rser=0
SYMBOL voltage -368 80 R90
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value SINE(0 110 600MEG)
SYMBOL cap -288 64 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 5pf
SYMBOL diode -16 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMBOL diode -160 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMBOL diode 16 192 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMBOL diode -128 64 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
TEXT -320 -152 Left 2 ;Recifier
TEXT -992 536 Left 2 !.tran 0 20s 1s 1s


Please post a screenshot of the schematic

Are you sure you need to simulate it for 20 seconds? You're looking at a 600MHz source, and let's say it needs at least 10 simulation timesteps per cycle. That's 600e61020 = 1.2e11 simulation timesteps; totally impractical if you want the answer anytime soon, not to mention storing the results! Why don't you try changing 20s to 100ns and see if that gets you what you're looking for?

This looks like a problem for average mode analysis. Think about ways you could convert the left-hand side into a Thevenin equivalent source.

20 mF at ... 600 MHz ? Simulation during 20 s ?

You are being unrealistic in your expectations for a SPICE simulation. To properly simulate what you show in the schematic involves 600e6 x 20 = 12e9 cycles of the input waveform (600 MHz). The step size would need to be on the order of 20 ps, not 1 second as shown in the .tran card. With the input capacitor = 5 pF, that's a capacitive reactance of about 53 ohms giving you a time constant of 1 second with the 20 mF output capacitor.
Perhaps the following suggestions will help:

Limit the simulation to about 20 us (12e3 cycles) and clear the Time
to start saving data and Maximum timestep settings.
Use a 100 nF output capacitor to shorten the time constant.
Use a real diode like a RB715F (chosen randomly from the LTspice diode selection). The "D" model is causing problems
with the solver.


Thanks for the reply. I've talked with my supervisor, but unless he has a supercomputer hidden this is not possible. Can't adjust the output capacitor; it's crucial for charging a large part of the circuit. Considering MATLAB's more powerful Simulink, but concerned about integrating the rest of the circuit. V1's an amp setup with a 555 timer for keying, and C2's got an LDO for voltage. I've attached an image below, but it takes 10 seconds to charge the output capacitor.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZWaIXVPdx7il_P484ID6Vnn9ET02ZlAd/view?usp=sharing
